# Spark Streaming - textFileStream: Tmp file error

Tags: scala, file, filesystems, spark-streaming, temporary-files

I have an Spark Streaming application that is scanning declared directory via `textFileStream` method. I have batch set to 10 seconds and I'm processing new files and concatenate their content into bigger parquet files. Files are downloaded/created directly in declared directory and that's cause me an issue I cannot bypass.
Lets get following scenario as example:
Directory is empty for most of a time, then around 100 small files come in the same time as streaming batch triggers. Spark stream founds 70 files with `.json` extension and 30 files with `_tmp` (still under creation/download). This situation obviously crash my app since process try to work with `_tmp` file witch in the meantime changed into fully created/downloaded `.json` file.
I've tried to filter out the rdd with following method:

```
val jsonData = ssc.textFileStream("C:\\foo").filter(!_.endsWith("tmp"))
```

But it still cause

```
jsonData.foreachRDD{ rdd=>
  /.../
}
```

to process _tmp files and throws exception of `no such file as *_tmp`

## Question

I've read about some staging directory from which I should move files after create/download process finish, but copy nor move(why is that? copy operation creates new file so...) operation doesn't trigger `textFileStream` and process is ignoring those files. Is there any other method to filter out those files and wait till they are complete before processing?

## Env spec

- Directory on Windows 8.1 file system, eventually that would be a Unix like machine
- Spark 1.5 for Hadoop 2.6

Comment: Did you fix it on Windows?

Comment: @up nope, eventually we made sub-process that migrates files from staging directory (let them fully download) to streaming directory. That did the job, second option is to extend batch delay. But this still brings some risk to the process.

Comment: I read again your question and I guess my pb is less restrictive, I'm not able to stream the directory on Windows. Did you stream a HFDS directory (/tmp/hive) on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `.filter(!_.endsWith("tmp"))` will filter the content of files inside `c:\foo`, it means the data, by default line by line. If it finds a line (not a filename) ending with `tmp` will remove it from the stream.